# How can I parse a DateTime from a string containing extra characters?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a string. The string is like this

> Hello I am a Coder, My DOB is 12/09/2011.

I want to extract the date from this sentence.  How do I do this using C#? I do not want regular expressions. This was an interview question asked to me recently.

This is my try

```
string myStr = "Hello 12/3/2013";
            DateTime s;
            DateTime.TryParse(myStr,out s);
            Console.WriteLine(s);
```

I am getting the output as

```
01-01-0001 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both C# and JavaScript support regular expressions. You can use this pattern to find that section of the string:

```
\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}
```

Of course that doesn't ensure that it's a valid date, e.g. `13/88/0000` would match that pattern. You'd then have to parse the string using something like `Date.Parse`.

---

However, since you've stated regular expressions are not an option, here's a *very crude* one-liner:

```
var input = "Hello I am a Coder, My DOB is 12/09/2011.";
DateTime date = new DateTime();
input.Split().SkipWhile(s => !DateTime.TryParse(s, out date)).Any();

Console.WriteLine(date); // 12/9/2011 12:00:00 AM
```

Comment: Month and day may only have 1 digit, you should probably account for that

Comment: @aaronman I considered it, but OP's string has `12/09/2011`, so I assumed that wouldn't be necessary.

Comment: well I didn't downvote or anything, u might as well include the `Date.parse` all you have to write is `Date.parse("12/09/2011")`

Answer (score 2):

Since you don't want to use REGEX, simply split the string on space and then use `DateTime.TryParseExact` to see if any string gets parsed as `DateTime`

```
string str = "Hello I am a Coder, My DOB is 12/09/2011";
string[] array = str.Split();//splits on space
string dateFormat = "M/d/yyyy"; //works with both single digit and double digit 
                                //(day/month) for parsing
                                //or d/M/yyyy depending your date culture
DateTime tempDateTime;
var result = array.FirstOrDefault(r => 
                                    DateTime.TryParseExact
                                            (r, 
                                            dateFormat, 
                                            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                                            DateTimeStyles.NoCurrentDateDefault, 
                                            out tempDateTime));
```

Your `result` would contain the Date string, and your `tempDateTime` would contain the parsed `DateTime`.